# SharedPreferences getInstance Error Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I'm in testing and I got this error when I'm calling `await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

The error :

```
Unexpected character (at character 477)
...b\\\",\\\"body\\\":\\\"ab\\\"}\"]}"}\":\\\"Description\\\",\\\"datePost\...
```

The test :

```
test("Test getInstance", () async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  });
```

I **can't clear it** because I can't get the instance. (I know that I can call setMockInitialValues, but before that work perfectly).

Any suggest ?

Comment: run flutter clean and then flutter pub get command

Comment: That not work, but I found the solution. In folders of the user AppData -> Roaming -> flutter_tester and I delete the shared_preferences.json file